# facebook access token without using FB APP

Tags: facebook, token, facebook-access-token

I have to retrieve the access token of the user that is going to use my FF extension. The problem is that i cannot use the common function online because i dont have a FB APP and the Secret Number of a Facebbok APP that i can use. 
I have a FF extension, the user has to be logged in, and i want to retrieve with my extension the token of the user that is using my extension to let him using some function of my extension. 
Everything has to be made in Javascript, since that the FF extensions work with JS files. 
Making everything easier, I have a button that has to retrieve the token of the user that is using my extension, and after that i have some functions that are going to build links with the token of the user that is in front of the laptop, using my extension.

There is someone with some ideas ?

The only function that i found is:

```
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
          var access_token = response.session.access_token;
           alert(access_token);
        } else {
           alert('User is logged out');
        }
    });
```

but i dont know if it works, and when im trying to use that i receive as a message kind of NULL.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Short answer, no. You must create an FB APP

Comment: is it possible that i cannot retrieve the token making kind of parsing of the page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer... Graph API Explorer... cmon looks really strange !